# retreving data from .txt file to jsp page

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags, jspx

i have a course.txt file contaiong courses

```
CS120,Introduction to Web Site Development
CS122,Using Relational Databases and SQL
CS201,Introduction to Programming
CS202,Introduction to Object Oriented Programming,CS201
CS203,Programming with Data Structures,CS202
CS320,Web and Internet Programming,CS120 CS122 CS203
```

and i want to display this data on web page using jsp, it looks like [image: table with 4 fields]

i have loaded the txt file into the program...`

```
String jspPath = session.getServletContext().getRealPath("/res"); String txtFilePath = jspPath+ "/cources.txt"; System.out.println(txtFilePath);` BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(txtFilePath));`
```

how can i extract data from txt file and display in table?

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, you look like you have a typo, it's spelled courses, not cources, second of all, how are we going to tell you how to parse the structure of the text file if we dont know what it looks like? add more information to your post, for example, what the data looks like.

This also looks suspiciously like a homework assignment